# Tar extract command, Cannot open: Permission denied

Tags: file-permissions, tar

I use `tar -zxvf tarFile.tar.gz` to extract the tarFile, but there is an error hint `tar: subfile :Cannot open: Permission denied` . 
I am a root user, and the permission of `tarFile.tar.gz` is 755, and the directory of the tarFile is also 755.
Execute`tar -tvf tarFile.tar.gz` tells the sub files permission is 644.
As the attached pic show.

[image]

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -3):

Try with `sudo` command:

```
sudo tar -zxvf tarFile.tar.gz
```

Comment: Any alternate way of resolving this without sudo in my case the extraction is a shell script , cannot sudo